# Meanings of bits in trigger type field (tgtype) of Postgres pg_trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Where can I find documentation on bits of POSTGRES tgtype, ex.:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_trigger;
===>
 tgtype = 23;
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`tgtype` is a ([per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-trigger.html)):

> Bit mask identifying trigger firing conditions

But individual bits are not identified there.
The [source code says](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/catalog/pg_trigger.h):

> ```
> 41  int16  tgtype;  /* BEFORE/AFTER/INSTEAD, UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT,
> 42                                   * ROW/STATEMENT; see below */
>
> ...
>
> 93  /* Bits within tgtype */
> 94  #define TRIGGER_TYPE_ROW         (1 << 0)
> 95  #define TRIGGER_TYPE_BEFORE      (1 << 1)
> 96  #define TRIGGER_TYPE_INSERT      (1 << 2)
> 97  #define TRIGGER_TYPE_DELETE      (1 << 3)
> 98  #define TRIGGER_TYPE_UPDATE      (1 << 4)
> 99  #define TRIGGER_TYPE_TRUNCATE    (1 << 5)
> 100 #define TRIGGER_TYPE_INSTEAD     (1 << 6)
> 101
> 102 #define TRIGGER_TYPE_LEVEL_MASK  (TRIGGER_TYPE_ROW)
> 103 #define TRIGGER_TYPE_STATEMENT   0
> ```

**`23`** translates to **`00010111`** in the least significant 8 bits, which should stand for:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_name();
```

A couple of quick tests in existing databases of mine seem to confirm it.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks rlib and Erwin. 
This was exactly what I was looking for.

I put together a query for this. I'll leave it here if anyone else needs it.

```sql
SELECT 
  n.nspname as schema_name, 
  c.relname as table_name, 
  t.tgname as trigger_name, 
  proname as function_name,
  tgtype::int::bit(7) as condition_bits,
  CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0000001')::int = 0 THEN 'STATEMENT' ELSE 'EACH ROW' END as cond_row,
  COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0000010')::int = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'BEFORE' END,
    CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0000010')::int = 0 THEN 'AFTER' ELSE NULL END,
    CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'1000000')::int = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'INSTEAD' END,
    ''
  )::text as cond_timing, 
    (CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0000100')::int = 0 THEN '' ELSE ' INSERT' END) ||
    (CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0001000')::int = 0 THEN '' ELSE ' DELETE' END) ||
    (CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0010000')::int = 0 THEN '' ELSE ' UPDATE' END) ||
    (CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0100000')::int = 0 THEN '' ELSE ' TRUNCATE' END)
  as cond_event
FROM pg_trigger t
JOIN pg_proc p ON t.tgfoid = p.oid
JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = t.tgrelid
JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace;
```

Edit:

Hmm, that was overkill. It turns out that the above bit-work is already done in the `triggers` view in the `information_schema` schema.

Easier: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.triggers`

Comment: It seems the `INSTEAD` is unreachable, your conditions for `AFTER` and `BEFORE` are the same so either of the two `CASE` expression will produce non-`NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, these answers saved me some time. Regarding the last answer, it is **not** overkill, if you have `TRUNCATE` triggers. I just noticed the other day that such triggers are **not** included in `information_schema.triggers`. As I either remember, or speculate..., this is a conscious choice. `TRUNCATE` is non-standard, and I *think* the core Postgres folks are strict about not making `information_schema` non-standard at all.

I did a tiny revision to the posted code for myself, posted here for anyone else who wants such a thing.

```
SELECT 
  c.relnamespace::regnamespace::text as schema_name, 
  tgrelid::regclass                  as table_name,
  t.tgname                           as trigger_name, 
  proname                            as function_name,
  tgtype::int::bit(7)                as condition_bits,
  CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0000001')::int = 0 THEN 'STATEMENT' ELSE 'EACH ROW' END
                                     as trigger_scope,
  COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0000010')::int = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'BEFORE' END,
    CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0000010')::int = 0 THEN 'AFTER' ELSE NULL END,
    CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'1000000')::int = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 'INSTEAD' END,
    ''
  )::text                           as trigger_timing, 
    (CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0000100')::int = 0 THEN '' ELSE ' INSERT' END) ||
    (CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0001000')::int = 0 THEN '' ELSE ' DELETE' END) ||
    (CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0010000')::int = 0 THEN '' ELSE ' UPDATE' END) ||
    (CASE WHEN (tgtype::int::bit(7) & b'0100000')::int = 0 THEN '' ELSE ' TRUNCATE' END)
                                     as trigger_action,
pg_get_triggerdef(t.oid)             as trigger_definition
  
FROM pg_trigger t
JOIN pg_proc p      ON t.tgfoid = p.oid
JOIN pg_class c     ON c.oid    = t.tgrelid
```